# Compare image in Java using ImageMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick

How to write the code in java  to compare 2 images if they're the same or not  using image magick?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try taking a look at : [https://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) has quite a few wrappers for ImageMagick in basically every langauge incl. Java

Comment: Not really understand it :( can you give me the code example?